# Taylor Series $4\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

Having trouble finding the first four terms of the Taylor series for the function $4\cos(x)$ about the point $a = \pi$

So I got the first term $4\cos(\pi),$ the second term $-4\sin(\pi)/1!,$ and the fourth term $4\sin(\pi)/3!,$ but I can't get the 3rd term. I thought it was $-4\cos(\pi)/2!$ but i'm not sure why it's not!

Answer (score 0):

it is much easier to make a change of variable before doing taylor expansion. let us make a change of variable $x = \pi + u, u = x - \pi.$ with this we have 
$$\begin{align}4 \cos x &= 4 \cos(\pi + u) = -4\cos u \\
&= -4\left(1 - \frac{u^2}{2!} + \frac{u^4}{4!} +   \cdots \right)\\
&=-4+4(x-\pi)^2/2! -4(x-\pi)^4/4! + \cdots \end{align}$$